# How to upgrade openwrt without losing the configuration?

Tags: configuration, firmware, openwrt

I need to make a script to upgrade my router without losing the configuration files and packages installed on the router.

I tried to repeat the same behavior of the interface in my script (I used the command sysupgrade) but I lost the config.

Besides, I have tried the upgrade with the interface with the option keep luci but it does not work too, I lost all the data router.

The command sysupgrade does not retain the configuration.

Is there anyone who offer me a solution?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You might want to consider asking this over at SuperUser or maybe even ServerFault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "Backup & Restore" feature from the webUI (luci) to save/load configuration files to/from you PC.